# Passing a method-reference to an objects constructor

Tags: java, parameter-passing, simplify

I feel that I'm missing something when it comes to statically typed languages. When I pretty much only used perl way back, there were many ways I could tell an object which function to call.

Now that I'm in Java, I fail to see how I can do something similar in an easy fasion

I have a generic `Button` class. This is subclassed by all of the actual buttons that will be used: Each with a different method to call when clicked.

Is there really no way of passing a reference to a method to call when clicked, so that I can use one class for all of the buttons?

At present, I create buttons like this:

```
// Specifically using the subclass that sets "firemode" to "close"
FiremodeClose fc = new FiremodeClose(Settings.ui_panel_start, Settings.ui_panel_row_firemode, game);
painter.addSelectionButton(fc);
clickTracker.addSelectionButton(fc);
```

This ofcourse couses a myriad of subclasses, each one differing only in placement, label/graphics, and method call. It makes more sense to do something similar to this:

```
// Generic button, the method that sets "firemode" is somehow passed as arguement to the contsructor.
Button fc = new Button(&referenceToFunctionToCallWhenClicked, otherArguementsEtc);
painter.addSelectionButton(fc);
clickTracker.addSelectionButton(fc);
```

Like I said, I feel I must be missing something, because it makes sense that there should be a way of achieving this, thus letting me getting away with just one `Button` class without any subclasses.

Comment: This is what an interface is for. Java 8 and Groovy make inline interface implementations for use cases like this simple.

Comment: ^^^ That, and see also anonymous classes.

Comment: @chrylis If that's what interfaces are for, then I must've been using them for something else than their intended purpose. I'd love to see an answer involving some code examples for this.

Comment: This is not the *only* use for interfaces, but it's a core one. An interface is the strongly-typed version of duck typing, declaring what particular functionality you need while not caring about the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If that's what interfaces are for, then I must've been using them for something else than their intended purpose. I'd love to see an answer involving some code examples for this.

Have your `Buttons` implement the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), just like [Swing does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)). Then you can even just use Swing's [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface, or even [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is not a bad choice, or e.g. roll your own:

```
// Your interface.
public interface MyButtonListener {
    public void buttonClicked ();
}

// Somewhere else:
Button fc = ...;
fc.addButtonListener(new MyButtonListener () {
    @Override public void buttonClicked () {
        // do stuff here
    }
});

// And in your Button have it simply iterate through all of its registered
// MyButtonListeners and call their buttonClicked() methods.
```

There are myriads of other ways to implement this. For example, you could even do something like:

```
public interface ThingThatCaresAboutButtons {
    public void buttonClicked (Button button);
}
```

Then have your higher level UI logic be something like:

```
public class MyUI implements ThingThatCaresAboutButtons {
    @Override public void buttonClicked (Button button) {
        if (button == theOneButton) {
            // do whatever
        } else if (button == theOtherButton) {
            // do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

And when creating buttons:

```
theOneButton = new Button(theUI, ...);
theOtherButton = new Button(theUI, ...);
```

Or have them maintain a list instead of a single object passed in the constructor. Or whatever.

Endless ways to skin this cat but hopefully you get some inspiration here. Check out how Swing works.

Answer (score 1):

You could for instance use `Runnable`:

```
class MyButton {
    private final Runnable action;

    public MyButton(Runnable action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    ...
}
```

And then call `action.run()` when the button is clicked.

Then when creating a button, you can pass a [reference to a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), as long as it has the `void` return type, and takes no arguments.

```
Button fc = new Button(EnclosingClass::methodToCall, otherArguementsEtc);
```

Other interfaces can be used for different method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use both method references and lambdas:

```
class Button {
    Button(Runnable function) {
    }
}
Button b1 = new Button(() -> System.out.println("works!"));
Button b2 = new Button(System::gc);
```

You can do similar thing in Java <8, but it's more verbose with anonymous classes:

```
Button b3 = new Button(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("works!");
    }
});
```